# FileNotFound error when registering workflow assembly

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I'm using the CRM Plugin Registration Tool to load a custom activity onto our CRM Server.  My custom activity extends `System.Activities.CodeActivity`.  However, whenever I try to regester the assembly, the following error appears:

`Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Activities, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at System.Reflection.Assembly._GetExportedTypes()
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExportedTypes()
   at PluginRegistrationTool.AssemblyReader.RetrievePluginsFromAssembly(String path) in C:\Users\sblessing\Desktop\sdk\tools\pluginregistration\AssemblyReader.cs:line 60
   at PluginRegistrationTool.AssemblyReader.RetrievePluginsFromAssembly(String path)
   at PluginRegistrationTool.RegistrationHelper.RetrievePluginsFromAssembly(String pathToAssembly) in C:\Users\sblessing\Desktop\sdk\tools\pluginregistration\RegistrationHelper.cs:line 49
   at PluginRegistrationTool.PluginRegistrationForm.btnLoadAssembly_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\sblessing\Desktop\sdk\tools\pluginregistration\PluginRegistrationForm.cs:line 127`

Where do I need to copy my assemblies to get rid of this error?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll want to debug this using the [Fusion log viewer.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx)  Just make sure to run it as admin, turn on the log, and reboot before attempting to debug.  You'll see where the CLR is looking for the assembly, and what version, and from there determine why it isn't being found (if you even have it installed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check following..
1. CRM must support 4.0 framework.
2. Refere Workflow DLLs (System.Activity and others) at CRM or copy all these into directory.